# Wordpress redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, canonical-link

I have a wordpress installation on a `wp` folder.

I need my clients write

`www.example.com`

in the browser, and the page

`'about'`

to be displayed, preserving the `www.example.com` address, not showing the `www.example.com/wp/about/` address.

Which are the proper way to do this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update WordPress.

This bug is not present in current versions...

Answer (score 1):

You can assign it by go to setting -> Reading and choose the page you want to display at `Front page displays`. You can choose either page or posts.

[image]

Comment: I already have them under that choice. What i need is to fix the 'redirect'/'hide redirected address' issue

Comment: Did you change .htaccess by any chances ?? coz it's normally work when it's change via setting

Comment: Of course i changed it, for redirecting. What i need is to hide the redirection...

Comment: Under that setting, and deleting the `.htaccess` works for the redirecting, but this does not hide the `about` page on the browser (unless there is another option around)... The main address keeps being: `www.example.com/about/`